# How to bind the '+' and '-' keys is Tcl/Tk

Tags: bind, tcl, tk-toolkit

How can I bind the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys to commands in Tcl/Tk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this particular problem:

```
set foo "t:"
pack [label .l -textvar foo]
bind . <Key-plus> {append foo "+"}
bind . <Key-KP_Add> {append foo "(+)"}
bind . <Key-minus> {append foo "-"}
bind . <Key-KP_Subtract> {append foo "(-)"}
```

But in general you can find the key name by running "xev" and pressing that key.

Comment: Alternatively, start wish, run `bind . <Key> {puts %K}` in it and then press the necessary keys in the wish window--it will print the corresponding "keysyms" on the console.  This is cross-platform compared to `xev` only found in X Window.